# Plot the region given by inequaities

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

How can one visualize the regions of intersection of the following

```
f[x_,z_]=(-2 + 2 z + x)/(-2 + 2 x); and 
0 <= y <= 1 && 0 < x < 1 && 2 z > x && 2 z + x < 2
```

Comment: `f[x_,z_]=(-2 + 2 z + x)/(-2 + 2 x);` is just a function,we should use it to defined a region. What is the definition of such region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Plot3D[f[x, z],
 {x, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1},
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{x, z}, 
   0 <= z <= 1 && 0 < x < 1 && 2 z > x && 2 z + x < 2]]
```

[image]

(You have a typo using $y$ instead of $z$.). And your function $f(x,z)$ is a *function*, not a region, so I think your question is ambiguous.